What are existing ways to do logical CZ gates on the surface code?
The surface code is a CSS code, so assuming all-to-all connectivity (unrealistic on most physical platforms), the logical CNOT can be implemented transversally. In a biplanar architecture, the setup to implement transversal CNOT can be accomplished by placing one surface code patch over another. Aside, from this lattice surgery and puncturing & braiding methods exist.
I want to ask in a similar vein, what are all the known ways to implement the logical controlled-phase (CZ) gate on the surface code?
(L.S. and braiding ought to work for implementing both logical CNOT and CZ gates, so it would be nice to know what are the leading methods preferred by the community!)

If you have all-to-all connectivity you effectively have folded surface codes, and so can perform a constant-depth Hadamard and a constant-depth CX. You can build a constant depth CZ out of those.
For lattice surgery, a CZ is a pipe with a domain wall connected to the two target qubits using Z type junctions.

For example, you can see it amongst Figure 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08916:




thanks for the answer and diagram!
A couple of follow-up questions - Firstly, when applying transversal Hadamard to all qubits, we would switch X and Z type stabilizers. I assume we apply transversal CNOT in a biplanar setup after. How exactly does one get the original orientation back?
Also, for the second possibility using lattice surgery, it seems a slightly different kind of lattice surgery than I've seen before, since we're using a magic state CZ|++> instead of multi-Pauli measurements? Since CZ is Clifford and potentially doesn't need magic, is this choice helpful?

@clearski When you have all-to-all connectivity, you can fix the patch orientation with non-local swap gates. The swap gates travel across a diagonal line of symmetry of the patch; this line is the "fold" in the folded surface code and the connections used by the swap gates are the additional adjacencies added by the folding. For the second part the interpretation of the diagram as involving a magic state is just an interpretation. You can make similar interpretations of the CNOT gate. All that matters is that topologically they are linked by a pipe with a domain wall using Z type junctions.

I see, the folding explainer makes sense!
Reg the second part, what is a Z type junction?

@clearski There are two types of junction that can appear in lattice surgery; the type that's used twice when measuring ZZ (Z type) and the one that's used twice when measuring XX (X type). If you use X type instead of Z type when trying to do a CZ, you'll do an X-controlled-X instead of a CZ. In defect diagrams you can tell them apart by the color of the "T" or "+" face on the junction.
